# How to persist a local storage data when user get redirected to subdomain

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a react app where users get redirected to the subdomain when they log in or signup. But the problem is After they get redirected to a subdomain, they need to log in again on the subdomain, and I also don't have access to the user's local storage data and redux state from the subdomain.

I'm redirecting a user using this code:

```
window.location.href = `http://${data?.result?.username}.localhost:3000/`;
```

Anyone, please guide me!

Comment: I think it is better to send user data as a parameter for the first time and save it to the local storage

Comment: But I don't want to keep that user data on the parameter the whole time. I want to remove that parameter after saving user data to local storage. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You must be able to have generated token from the API where you requested your login credentials. This token must be a known contract from both client side and backend side.

When you are able to have that information, set that token together with the  URL as a query string after the login succeeded. Since you cannot use or access storage across different tab sessions.

```
window.location.href =`http://${data?.result?.username}.localhost:3000?token=${your-token-from-login-api-response}`;
```

Then on the first load of your app in the different subdomain get the set query params and parse it in a way to identify if the user is already authenticated.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const token = urlParams.get('token');
```

Comment: You mean I should use that token in which I encoded user data on the backend and then decode it on the frontend and save the user data on the local storage. Am i right?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can also explore other Web Storage API's available, like the session storage or cookies especially if you are dealing with sensitive information.